# jQuery Each() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a class to each div.banner inside of my #destaques, but isn't working. What's happening?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  bannerRotator("#destaques");
});



function bannerRotator(element) {

  // Conta quantos banners existem:

  i = 0;

  $(element).find(".banner").each(function() {
    i++;
    $(this).addClass("test");
  });

  alert(i);

  //

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="destaques">
<div class="banner"><img src="images/001.jpg"/></div>
<div class="banner"><img src="images/002.jpg"/></div>
<div class="banner"><img src="images/003.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var i = $('#destaques .banner').addClass('test').length`,

Comment: [Working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/LKw2X/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`addClass` will work on a collection automatically.

```
$("#destaques").find(".banner").addClass("test");
```

**Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/rNN8X/1/).**

*side note*: this could be also be simplified to

```
$("#destaques .banner").addClass("test");
```

Comment: You can simplify that even further with a selector: $("#destaques .banner").addClass("test");

Comment: @FarligOpptreden, thanks for the reminder, updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery.each($("div.banner"), function() {
  i++;
  $(this).addClass("test");
});
```

But if you just want to add the class you can also do it in the following one liner

```
alert($('div.banner').addClass("test").length);
```